# Объединить метки [маршрутизатор], [роутер] и [router]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [маршрутизатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80), [роутер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%be%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80) и [router](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router), так как они являются одним и тем же понятием. [router](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router) - в переводе с английского это [маршрутизатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80).
В качестве основной предлагаю сделать русскоязычную метку [маршрутизатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80)

---

*Дополнительна информация о метках:*

- метка [маршрутизатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80) - 34 вопроса, есть полное описание;
- метка [роутер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%be%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80) - 105 вопросов, описание отсутствует;
- метка [router](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router) - 65 вопросов, описание отсутствует.

---

В вопросах не относящихся к понятию [маршрутизатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80), предлагаю убрать данную метку или же сменить на более подходящую.

Comment: Лучше отдельный вопрос-голосование задать и в ответах опубликовать вариант, за которые сообщество будет голосовать.

Comment: В этом вопросе можно обсудить варианты и т.п. (:

Answer (score 1):

Бывает ещё такой [роутер/router](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router+javascript) (9 вопросов) и [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router+php) (15 вопросов) и т.д.

И почему-то мне кажется, что по метке [router](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/router) вопросов именно про роутинг в приложении больше, чем когда подразумевают [маршрутизатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80).

Comment: Согласен, по router в основном вопросы по роутингу в приложениях.

Comment: @L.F.C. а не наоборот?